# Liferay server fails to start on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, liferay

When I start a [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) server in the servers of Eclipse, it fails to start and I get this error in the Eclipse log file:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d99863d, pid=1908, tid=2196
>
> JRE version: 7.0_03-b05
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x16863d]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

I installed the latest version of JDK but it didn't help.

Any suggestions for how to get Liferay running on Windows?

Comment: Are you using pure eclipse or the Liferay IDE plugins (or Developer Studio)? Which versions of Liferay/Eclipse/IDE are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using Liferay IDE. By the way when I start bundled tomcat by running "start.bat" file, it starts without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

set jre6 in eclipse: `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`

or set it only for Liferay Runtime Environment:  `Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Envirenments -> Edit -> JRE`